# "I don't know how" type questions

Tags: discussion

What is the best way of dealing with questions asking how to do something? I'm talking specifically about questions where the OP has made a reasonable attempt, provided some code, but does not know what to do next.

These questions usually meet with a negative response and close votes, but I think that's probably a bit harsh for newbies who *have* actually made some effort.

What are the guidelines for such instances?

**Example here:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764433/im-new-to-java-i-want-to-know-how-do-i-sum-up-a-users-input-and-and-get-an-avera/33764631#33764631

In this question the OP has done a reasonable start, just does not know where to go next. But notice there are 2 unwarranted close votes, and 2 questionable downvotes

Comment: Most of these should be simply closed as _too broad_. If they made efforts and showing failed attempts, these questions are answerable most of the time.

Comment: Upvote them, we need more questions like that (unless they are poor quality, then downvote!). This is the type of question that will help a lot of users in the future if they aren't duplicates. Certainly more useful than *"Why is my code not working? I get error: `undefined is not a function`"*

Comment: I find your description of the questions that concern you a bit vague; examples would help. There's some good guidance about this kind of thing [in jmac's puzzle analogy on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/159251), though.

Comment: @JoshCaswell example added as per request

Comment: @NickJ That question is just a code dump (without a MCVE) no description of the problem or why the code isn't working, no indication of what he doesn't understand, etc.  It's a code dump followed by "plz fix".  That's not at all a quality question.  It's not even a case of a user asking for a concept to be explained; it's just asking for some broken code to be fixed.

Comment: code dump without specific question is not a good question, it is *fix this code I found on the internet to do what I need so I can get back to drinking and playing Fallout 4 as quickly as possible*.

Comment: In this scenario, the question is off-topic; it's not really asking a coherent question.  Even if I were to edit it into shape (which I was in the process of), this sort of question is still pretty off topic.

Comment: Looking at this that way, you're right. I guess I'm a bit of a softie. Having said that, I never just write code for them, I give them an example to follow instead. Otherwise they'll never learn.

Comment: I am not arguing if the question is on topic, but it is a bit strange that a broad question would become non-broad if some evidence of attempt is added, or is there a close reason about lacking attempt?

Comment: @amuse Sometimes the text of the question is too broad, but having specific code examples makes it clear what the asker hopes to achieve.  But there's no general rule that showing effort makes a question not too-broad.  There's also no rule requiring effort be shown -- for clear, relatively simple questions, showing past attempts may even detract from the question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Don't be a jerk about their lack of understanding, and if the question is on topic **and** you are so inclined, feel encouraged to answer.

The only ones you want to close are the ones who don't show any clear efforts; that is, the question that reads something like this:

> I would like to *foo* the *bar* in Java, but I don't know how.  Could someone help me?

That is less preferable to a question like this:

> I am attempting to *foo* the *bar* in Java through use of a `TreeSet`.  I've attempted to create a *baz* to help, but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your first question is missing, "well researched" and "appropriately scoped".  Lots of questions stemming from a lack of understanding of a core concept are going to be Too Broad, and many core concepts also have lots of readily discoverable quality resources covering them.

Comment: I disagree that the second question is significantly better than the former. If using a `TreeSet` and a `baz` is a good idea, then it'll be covered in the answers to the first question anyway. If it's a *bad* idea, then the second question will become a worthless mess as half of the content of the answers ends up being devoted to either guiding the OP away from their mistaken choice of tools or else to how to *foo* the *bar* within their idiotic choice of constraints. I'd rather have the first question, always.

Comment: @MarkAmery Agreed. People are upbraided for not making an effort if they don't give enough details, but if they incorporate details about their (misguided) efforts into the question they're now upbraided for making it an XY problem. *sigh*. It's doubly sad from the perspective of "making a database of questions and answers", because people in the future who want to *foo* the *bar* in Java and come here from a Google search might not even care about TreeSets - they just care about the best way to *foo* the *bar* in Java. (And *their* "making an effort" *is* by searching Google/StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 4):

If you can leave them with something, then leave it in comments or a custom close message.

Don't choose one of the stock reasons for the sake of "gosh this looks like just a good enough reason" and be lazy about it. They are your fellow programmers. They need help.

Take a stand. Your name is attached to it.

Remember, you are trying to help someone out there. You should not be a part of the mass crowd, herd mentality. Leave some `breadcrumbs` they can cling to and solve it from.

Otherwise, you are not helping them. And us.

Edit: 
[Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779686/selecting-different-rows-from-two-different-tables-in-one-query#comment55350878_33779686)

And also there is the attachment of your name next to the prevailing reason for closure, whether or not that was yours. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/201932) as a background. As such, you might be left defending a reason for closure, when it wasn't even yours to begin with. Example, I close for reason of Unclear, others go for Too Broad. The result, I need to defend Too Broad.