# Incorrect user is shown at closed question

Tags: support, feature-request, vote-to-close, closed-questions

There was a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34569648/2675154) asked earlier today, so I thought of closing the question, but in the close popup already two other users voted to close as unclear.

Still I went ahead and closed it as duplicate question. Now it is showing:

> marked as duplicate by davidism, Shadow, VR46

But I am the only one who closed it as duplicate. Is this the way it works or is something wrong here?

Comment: It's not a bug. Whether it is good is a different question.

Comment: So you mean to say that is how to works. So if a another user marked the same question as `OFF-TOPIC` then will he be included as well.

Comment: I think there's some differentiating in regard to off-topic, but I'm not sure just now...

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yes; if there's disagreement about which off-topic reason to use, they'll all be listed.

Comment: This is a duplicate but I cannot find it here on meta. Most likely it's a [meta.se] duplicate, then. -- Found it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917

Comment: It is annoying and I sometime won't close a question because I don't want to see my name under a different close reason.

Comment: Same thing happened [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575591/timer-does-not-seem-to-fire). Look at the comments on that question.

Comment: I think that when a gold tag user (as VR46 in [sql]) votes to close as duplicate, the other users that voted to close for different reasons should not be listed. As @the_lotus mentioned, sometimes the user don't want to be listed under a different reason, but want to cast a close-vote.

Comment: @Mindwin No link there, and I can't actually find the question. Does said question actually exist, or did you write that comment expecting people to upvote it randomly?

Comment: @the_lotus if I feel strongly about it I go with a custom reason which would be left in comments automatically for me [This meta answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310511/1816093)

Comment: @cybermonkey link where? I didn't post a link, and I am not looking for comment upvotes. What question are you talking about? What part of my comment made you think there is a link?

Comment: @Mindwin Usually when someone comments 'Related:', a link to a related question follows. Your comment doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @cybermonkey my apologies, i was not aware of that custom. Comment removed

Comment: @Jongware - So whats the point of showing wrong information while closing questions

Comment: Did you read the meta post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment there can only be ONE close reason be shown in the close notice. The system either chooses the reason with the most votes or the reason that was used by the user with the binding vote.

In your case the duplicate was chosen as you used your dupe-hammer. The other users *lost* the vote.

As indicated by [Jongware](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2564301/jongware) there is a longstanding feature-request over on Meta Stack Exchange: [Distinguish close votes by reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason) and you're all invited to vote on that request.

Given the timelines for implementing feature requests, we're getting close to the 6 to 8 years timeframe so allow for another two years before this is implemented.